# MediaElement.js Flash Fallback With Audio Tag

Tags: mediaelement.js

I would like to implement an audio tag with Flash fallback. There are no examples on the site and I am unsure how to go about doing this. I have an MP3 that I would like to play and it works fine on Webkit browsers as expected however it does not work with Firefox and assumingly IE.

I have tried implementing something like this by mocking the video element with Flash fallback from examples.

```
<audio id="audio-bloop" controls="controls">
  <source src="audio/digital-boop.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
  <!-- Flash Fallback -->
  <object width="640" height="360" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flashmediaelement.swf">
      <param name="audio" value="videos/build/flashmediaelement.swf" />
      <param id="flashvars-param" name="flashvars" value="controls=falseg&file=audio/digital-boop.mp3" />
  </object>
</audio>
```

This, however, does not work. How can I go about providing Flash fallback support for audio tags using MediaElement.js?

**EDIT:**

I attempted this after viewing the source on the MediaElement.js home page:

```
<audio id="audio-bloop" controls="false" preload="auto" src="audio/digital-boop.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
```

Coupled with this:

```
audioPlayer = new MediaElementPlayer("#audio-bloop", {
        pluginPath: '../videos/build/',
        // name of flash file
        flashName: 'flashmediaelement.swf',
       // name of silverlight file
       silverlightName: 'silverlightmediaelement.xap'
});
```

And still had no success. Again, the video works fine in IE9, Safari, and Google Chrome, but no goin IE6-7 or Firefox and Opera.

EDIT: I was not able to get the Flash fallback working, so for the time being I am using another source tag to add a .wav format of the file.

Answer (score 3):

When I used Media Element JS (version 2.9.3) this is what I did for Audio element and it works in IE 8+, latest versions (as of this writing) of Firefox, Safari, Chrome.

***JS***

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/media-element/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('audio,video').mediaelementplayer();  
});
```

***HTML***

```
<audio id="player2" src="path.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls></audio>
```

***CSS***

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/path/media-element/mediaelementplayer.css" />
```

If HTML 5 is not supported the Flash fallback is automatically loaded.